# how to tokenize a set of documents into unigram + bigram bagofwords using gensim?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, gensim

I know from using scikit learn i could use,

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=2,ngram_range=(1, 2),norm='l2')

corpus = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
```

This piece of code. But how could i do this with gensim?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take a look at simple_preprocess from utils

> gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(doc, deacc=False, min_len=2,
>   max_len=15) Convert a document into a list of tokens.
>
> This lowercases, tokenizes, de-accents (optional). – the output are
>   final

tokens = unicode strings, that won’t be processed any further.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nltk`'s `everygrams` function is a good way to do this.

```
from nltk import everygrams

text = 'I like playing baseball'
grams = ['_'.join(grams) for grams in list(everygrams(text, 1, 2))]
grams

>> ['I', 'like', 'playing', 'baseball', 'I_like', 'like_playing', 'playing_baseball']
```

This will create all uni- and bigrams in the text.